# Body не растягивается по размеру экрана

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, design

Добрый день! Возникла проблема на сайте. если на странице мало контента то footer поднимается на верх и оставляет пустое белое место, коротко говоря body не привязан к размеру экрана. Пожалуйста подскажите в чем дело) Ссылка на сайт с такой проблемой внизу. Заранее спасибо!!!

[Ссылка на сайт с проблемой](http://nugbari.ge/ru/our-story/client.php?id=2)

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса, но подозркваю, что на хватает `html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}` , так как у  `body` изначатьно нет высоты

Comment: так проблема в том что это не помогает

Comment: ну тогда используй `flex`...  никогда не подведет

Comment: Все же не получилось разобратся

Comment: Для body задавай height: 100vh; - в этом случае его содержимое всегда (!) будет занимать 100% видимой ширины экрана.

Comment: это да но иногда на сайте можеть быть больше контента и скрол просто блокируется

Comment: С боди все ок. Он заполняет весь экран. Можно просто на боди бекграунд черный повесить, и будет не так броско. Что угодно, но пока у тебя контента с картинками недостаточно на высоту экрана, так и будет. В любом случае будет пустое место над или под футером, это уже от предпочтений)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body{
  min-height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:0;
}
header,footer{
  flex:0 0 auto;
  /*для наглядности*/
  height:50px;
  background-color:green;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
  
}
main{
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Шапка</header>
  <main></main>
  <footer>Подвал</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)) ваш код помог опустить footer на нормальную высоту. вот только за ним не растянулся background. Сейчас там белое пустое место [link](http://http://nugbari.ge/our-story/wholenuts.php?id=1) тут показано как. не могли бы вы подсказать как решить и эту проблему

Comment: В данном случае растягивается только основной блок контента 'main'. При этом, его дети не изменяют размеры. Задайте  background главному контент-блоку. В вашем случае -  section#content.

Comment: Огромное спасибо) вы очень помогли